# rosmatlab is gone?

Tags: ros, rosmatlab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I just wanted to reinstall all my Software to my new laptop and ended up with searching for rosmatlab.
Where is it gone?
On the former webpage [1], one can only find the "Robot Operating System (ROS) Support from Robotics System Toolbox" which is commercial.
There still exist the manual [2] for the package, but even google cannot help me with finding the old binaries :(.

[1] http://de.mathworks.com/hardware-support/robot-operating-system.html

[2] https://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/files/ros-io-package-getting-started-guide.pdf

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206974/rosmatlab-is-gone?/) by [tiko](https://answers.ros.org/users/1659/tiko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I got it [1].
All versions are gone, because auf the new implementation:

> The ROS I/O package, which was available on File Exchange previously has been removed due to the release of the new product, "Robotics System Toolbox", released in MATLAB R2015a. The new toolbox has the capability to interact with ROS. So, there is no method to have an interaction between ROS and MATLAB before R2015a.

[1] http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/195837-why-am-i-not-able-to-find-the-ros-i-o-package-previously-available-on-matlab-central

---

Originally posted by [tiko](https://answers.ros.org/users/1659/tiko/) with karma: 13 on 2015-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0